# Getting Transaction Information From Paypal through API

Tags: php, api, curl, paypal, transactions

I am trying to get old transaction details using paypal's API using this code:

```
<?php 
$info = 'USER=[username]'
        .'&PWD=[password]'
        .'&SIGNATURE=[signature]'
        .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
        .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
        .'&STARTDATE=2014-01-01T05:38:48Z'
        .'&ENDDATE=2014-01-02T05:38:48Z'
        .'&VERSION=94';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if($result == FALSE) { 
    echo "cURL error: " . curl_error($curl);
}

parse_str($result, $result);

foreach($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' => '.$value."<BR>";
}
```

I get an error message:

```
TIMESTAMP => 2014-07-01T10:57:55Z
CORRELATIONID => db47001bb195b
ACK => Failure
VERSION => 94
BUILD => 11562053
L_ERRORCODE0 => 10002
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 => Security error
L_LONGMESSAGE0 => Security header is not valid
L_SEVERITYCODE0 => Error
```

The end result of this piece of code is to search through transaction records looking for a specific transaction and relay that data back to the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid security header error is almost always related to your API credentials being incorrect. Double check your API username, password and signature. Also be sure to change your credentials when you move from the sandbox to live.

Comment: the API creds are correct, although I am not sure on how to switch from sandbox to live to test either. Do you have any experience on this?

Comment: The credentials for the live account will be different. you would get them from the live account profile.